# Issue in accessing data from Apache Ignite cache

Tags: ignite

### I setup ignite v2.3.0 on remote server. i connected from VS2015 in client mode and successfully put the data in cache. I am able to find single record but when accessing using IQueryCursor, getting the error "Failed to inject resource .." Please help identify issue.

### server configuration

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="binaryConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
        <property name="nameMapper">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryBasicNameMapper">
            <property name="simpleName" value="true"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
          <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>
                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                <value>x.x.x.x</value>
                <value>x.x.x.x</value>
               </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

---

### code used to save and read the cache

```
var ccfg = new CacheConfiguration
{
    Name = "SCAN_DATA"
};

var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
{
    SpringConfigUrl = @"D:\GitRepository\IgniteTest\IgniteTest\ignite-config.xml",
    BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person), typeof(PersonFilter)),
    ClientMode = true
};
using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
{
    ICache<int, Person> persons = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>(ccfg);

    //saving the record.. lstPerson contain Person objects
    foreach (Person p in lstPerson) persons.Put(i++, p);

    //getting single record-- working
    lstData.Add(persons.Get(1));

    //query with filter condition-- not working and i think i am missing something
    var scanQuery = new ScanQuery<int, Person>(new PersonFilter(30));
    IQueryCursor<ICacheEntry<int, Person>> queryCursor = persons.Query(scanQuery);

    //below line throwing error.. 
    foreach (ICacheEntry<int, Person> p in queryCursor)
    {
        int j = 0;
    }
}
```

---

### Model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class PersonFilter : ICacheEntryFilter<int, Person>
{
    public int _Age { get; set; }
    public PersonFilter(int age) { _Age = age; }

    public bool Invoke(ICacheEntry<int, Person> entry)
    {
        return entry.Value.Age >= _Age;
    }
}
```

### -- exception ex.ToString()

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Failed to inject resource [method=setIgniteInstance, target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@488dae55, rsrc=IgniteKernal [cfg=IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=2, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, igniteHome=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin, igniteWorkDir=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6f94fa3e, nodeId=277234ce-81a0-4ce8-8fd3-ea201cec7de5, marsh=org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller@1a5b602b, marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [], reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$ConnectGateway@2411a6c6, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$7@4cd606a8, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, srvLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2@d4d6d21, locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=0, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=GridNioServer [selectorSpins=0, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@1cd8c0b, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], closed=false, directBuf=true, tcpNoDelay=true, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, writeTimeout=2000, idleTimeout=600000, skipWrite=false, skipRead=false, locAddr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:47100, order=LITTLE_ENDIAN, sndQueueLimit=0, directMode=true, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c, sslFilter=null, msgQueueLsnr=null, readerMoveCnt=0, writerMoveCnt=0, readWriteSelectorsAssign=false], shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=false, connectionsPerNode=1, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=2000, lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$2@43023391, boundTcpPort=47100, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, rcvdMsgsCnt=28, sentMsgsCnt=26, rcvdBytesCnt=3617, sentBytesCnt=112683, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@25c06ab5[Count = 0], stopping=false, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@37f1104d, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentLocalStore$LocalDeploymentListener@2a4c3f51], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@49dc7102, addrRslvr=null, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, txCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.TransactionConfiguration@1d2a7598, cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=60000, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration@790ecaf5, odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=0, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=BinaryConfiguration [idMapper=null, nameMapper=BinaryBaseNameMapper [isSimpleName=true], serializer=null, compactFooter=true], memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration@673be18f, activeOnStart=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8]], igniteInstanceName=null, startTime=1514280958226, rsrcCtx=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridSpringResourceContextImpl@468cb2b9, reconnectState=org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal$ReconnectState@49da81ff]] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to inject resource [method=setIgniteInstance, target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@488dae55, rsrc=IgniteKernal [cfg=IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=2, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, igniteHome=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin, igniteWorkDir=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6f94fa3e, nodeId=277234ce-81a0-4ce8-8fd3-ea201cec7de5, marsh=org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller@1a5b602b, marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [], reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$ConnectGateway@2411a6c6, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$7@4cd606a8, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, srvLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2@d4d6d21, locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=0, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=GridNioServer [selectorSpins=0, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@1cd8c0b, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], closed=false, directBuf=true, tcpNoDelay=true, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, writeTimeout=2000, idleTimeout=600000, skipWrite=false, skipRead=false, locAddr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:47100, order=LITTLE_ENDIAN, sndQueueLimit=0, directMode=true, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c, sslFilter=null, msgQueueLsnr=null, readerMoveCnt=0, writerMoveCnt=0, readWriteSelectorsAssign=false], shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=false, connectionsPerNode=1, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=2000, lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$2@43023391, boundTcpPort=47100, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, rcvdMsgsCnt=28, sentMsgsCnt=26, rcvdBytesCnt=3617, sentBytesCnt=112683, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@25c06ab5[Count = 0], stopping=false, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@37f1104d, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentLocalStore$LocalDeploymentListener@2a4c3f51], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@49dc7102, addrRslvr=null, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, txCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.TransactionConfiguration@1d2a7598, cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=60000, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration@790ecaf5, odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=0, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=BinaryConfiguration [idMapper=null, nameMapper=BinaryBaseNameMapper [isSimpleName=true], serializer=null, compactFooter=true], memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration@673be18f, activeOnStart=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8]], igniteInstanceName=null, startTime=1514280958226, rsrcCtx=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridSpringResourceContextImpl@468cb2b9, reconnectState=org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal$ReconnectState@49da81ff]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformUtils.unwrapQueryException(PlatformUtils.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.query.PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.processOutStream(PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.java:98)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.outStream(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:93)
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@71529963, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=true, subjId=ab35945c-8904-40c5-96b8-e5c358b6e5d7, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1287)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:171)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$5.onHasNext(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:634)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.query.PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.processOutStream(PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.java:84)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@71529963, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=true, subjId=ab35945c-8904-40c5-96b8-e5c358b6e5d7, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.checkError(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.internalIterator(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:315)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:161)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to execute query on node [query=GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@71529963, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=true, subjId=ab35945c-8904-40c5-96b8-e5c358b6e5d7, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null], nodeId=277234ce-81a0-4ce8-8fd3-ea201cec7de5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.onPage(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryResponse(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:398)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.access$000(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:63)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1060)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$700(GridCacheIoManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$OrderedMessageListener.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1609)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4100(GridIoManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$GridCommunicationMessageSet.unwind(GridIoManager.java:2751)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.unwindMessageSet(GridIoManager.java:1515)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4400(GridIoManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$10.run(GridIoManager.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to inject resource [method=setIgniteInstance, target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@488dae55, rsrc=IgniteKernal [cfg=IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=2, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, igniteHome=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin, igniteWorkDir=C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6f94fa3e, nodeId=277234ce-81a0-4ce8-8fd3-ea201cec7de5, marsh=org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller@1a5b602b, marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [], reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$ConnectGateway@2411a6c6, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$7@4cd606a8, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, srvLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2@d4d6d21, locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=0, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=GridNioServer [selectorSpins=0, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@1cd8c0b, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], closed=false, directBuf=true, tcpNoDelay=true, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, writeTimeout=2000, idleTimeout=600000, skipWrite=false, skipRead=false, locAddr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:47100, order=LITTLE_ENDIAN, sndQueueLimit=0, directMode=true, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c, sslFilter=null, msgQueueLsnr=null, readerMoveCnt=0, writerMoveCnt=0, readWriteSelectorsAssign=false], shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=false, connectionsPerNode=1, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=2000, lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$2@43023391, boundTcpPort=47100, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, rcvdMsgsCnt=28, sentMsgsCnt=26, rcvdBytesCnt=3617, sentBytesCnt=112683, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@25c06ab5[Count = 0], stopping=false, metricsLsnr=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$3@3f1d919c], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@37f1104d, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [lsnr=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentLocalStore$LocalDeploymentListener@2a4c3f51], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@49dc7102, addrRslvr=null, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, txCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.TransactionConfiguration@1d2a7598, cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=60000, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration@790ecaf5, odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=0, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=BinaryConfiguration [idMapper=null, nameMapper=BinaryBaseNameMapper [isSimpleName=true], serializer=null, compactFooter=true], memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration@673be18f, activeOnStart=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8]], igniteInstanceName=null, startTime=1514280958226, rsrcCtx=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridSpringResourceContextImpl@468cb2b9, reconnectState=org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal$ReconnectState@49da81ff]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceUtils.inject(GridResourceUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceBasicInjector.inject(GridResourceBasicInjector.java:59)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceIoc$ClassDescriptor.injectInternal(GridResourceIoc.java:446)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceIoc$ClassDescriptor.inject(GridResourceIoc.java:470)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor.inject(GridResourceProcessor.java:278)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor.inject(GridResourceProcessor.java:162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.injectResources(GridCacheQueryManager.java:910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.scanIterator(GridCacheQueryManager.java:835)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.executeQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:620)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.queryResult(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1548)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1153)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:230)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1060)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:378)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceUtils.inject(GridResourceUtils.java:85)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Platforms are not available [nodeId=277234ce-81a0-4ce8-8fd3-ea201cec7de5] (Use Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start() or Apache.Ignite.exe to start Ignite.NET nodes; ignite::Ignition::Start() or ignite.exe to start Ignite C++ nodes).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformNoopProcessor.context(PlatformNoopProcessor.java:47)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformUtils.platformContext(PlatformUtils.java:715)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl.setIgniteInstance(PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl.java:91)
    ... 31 more

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.Error(Void* target, Int32 errType, SByte* errClsChars, Int32 errClsCharsLen, SByte* errMsgChars, Int32 errMsgCharsLen, SByte* stackTraceChars, Int32 stackTraceCharsLen, Void* errData, Int32 errDataLen)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.IgniteJniNativeMethods.TargetOutStream(Void* ctx, Void* target, Int32 opType, Int64 memPtr)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedUtils.TargetOutStream(IUnmanagedTarget target, Int32 opType, Int64 memPtr)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformJniTarget.OutStream[T](Int32 type, Func`2 readAction)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.Query.QueryCursorBase`1.RequestBatch()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.Query.QueryCursorBase`1.MoveNext()
   at IgniteTest.Form1.button6_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\GitRepository\IgniteTest\IgniteTest\Form1.cs:line 222
```

Comment: Please attach complete exception information (e.g. `ex.ToString()` output) so I can see full stack trace from .NET and Java.

Comment: sorry for late reply as i was on vacation. updated the exception section. also uploaded the code in git FYR. https://github.com/afzal4398/Ignite.git   please also check if configuration is correct or not and suggest right configuration for deployment. appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IgniteException: Platforms are not available... Use Apache.Ignite.exe to start Ignite.NET nodes

Looks like server node was started with `ignite.bat` or `ignite.sh` instead of `Apache.Ignite.exe`.

Certain Ignite.NET APIs, such as `ScanQuery`, require .NET on all nodes (start with `Apache.Ignite.exe`). Additionally, make sure that assembly with `PersonFilter` class is loaded on all server nodes.

- https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/platform-interoperability#section-mixed-platform-clusters
- https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/standalone-nodes#section-loading-user-assemblies

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. i did exactly same as you said. run 1 dotnet node with assembly configured <add key="Ignite.Assembly.1" value="IgniteTest.Library.dll"/> with same spring xml config. earlier issue gone but getting the "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Unknown pair [platformId=1, typeId=1113010418]" issue. on debug, found "'((Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.Query.QueryCursorBase<Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.ICacheEntry<int, IgniteTest.Library.Person>>)queryCursor).Current' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'". please help

Comment: i tried with SQL, LINQ and all places i am getting trouble during filtering. if taking all records from cache using ToList(), it is working, but with filter not working.  i am following your blog post code but not able to achieve the filter. I am completely stuck and no way to find the solution. Please help and look into my code and configuration at **github.com/afzal4398/Ignite.git** @Pavel Tupitsyn

Comment: thanks for the help. my issue resolved. my client running the java node and that is the reason i was getting issues.

Comment: @AfzalKhan thanks for the update, I'm glad the issue is resolved.